# RSS feed working fine in localhost but does not work on the server

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, rss

I m working on a website which extracts news feed from my blog to the website. It workd fine in my localhost but when the content is online, the same code does not work. Here are my code and here is the link for the website [here](http://thameltouristguidebaaluddharkendra.org.np/)...

```
   <?php
$i = 0; // counter
$j=0;
$des="";
$url = "http://lampsoftnepal.com/?feed=rss2"; // url to parse
$rss = simplexml_load_file($url); // XML parser
$dater=array();
$mylink=array();
$mytitle=array();
// RSS items loop

print '<h2><img style="vertical-align: middle;" src="'.$rss->channel->image->url.'" /> '.$rss->channel->title.'</h2>'; // channel title + img with src

foreach($rss->channel->item as $item) {
if ($i < 8) { // parse only 10 items
    //print $item->pubDate;
    $mylink[$i]=$item->link;
    $mytitle[$i]=$item->title;
    $dater[$i]=$item->pubDate;
    }



$i++;
}
print '<a href="'.$item->link[0].'" target="_blank">'.$item->title[1].'</a><br />';

//print $dater[1];


?>
```

Here is the code where i want to print the date

```
<div class="list-group"> 

            <div class="media list-group-item">


                  <a class="pull-left" href="news-events.html">
                    <img class="media-object" src="images/stree2.jpeg" alt="...">
                  </a>
                  <div class="media-body">
                      <a href="news-events.html">

                        <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Somae's Story <span class="news-date"><?php echo $dater[0]; ?></span></h4>
                        <p class="list-group-item-text">Lorem ipsum doner mata coma, orem ipsum doner mata coma, Lorem ipsum.</p>
                      </a>
                </div><!-- end of media-body -->
            </div><!-- end of media list-group-item -->

        </div><!-- end of list-group -->

        </div><!-- end of side-box -->
     </div>
```

Comment: In what way is it not working?

Comment: Actually!!! i have the code working fine in my localhost!!then i uploaded the file!!! If you see in the right sidebar!!! in the event and news section!!! the feeds does not appear!!i m trying to retrive the feeds from a wordpress blog!! link is www.lampsoftnepal.com

Comment: Is simplexml enabled on the server? And thesame PHP version on localhost and server?

Comment: yes smplexml is enabled in my server!!! you can check it here!! www.hariyalihost.com/check.php

Comment: I'm not going to follow links to random web sites (you might know it is OK, I do not). Rather you need to state the problem *here*.

Comment: When i use the function simple_xml_load in my local host it works well and extracts data from the website but when i use in my hosting server it doesn't load the contents from the rss feed. The variable show nothing.